# Getting "API Key not found. Please pass a valid API key" from GCP Identity Platform but the Key is absolutely correct

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to follow the tutorial here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ny92vcpOQFs
...but I get a 400 error back with the message "API Key not found. Please pass a valid API key".

The code section where the API key is provided is literally copied right from the GCP Identity Platform interface, and I have checked it multiple times.

I don't know where to go from here, all the tutorials just take it for granted that this works.

The minimal reproduction is as follows, although I get the same result if I try to use `firebase-ui-auth`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Identity Platform Test</title>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script> //this section copied directly from GCP
      var config = {
        apiKey: '<Private but 100% correct>',
        authDomain: 'my-site.firebaseapp.com',
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>

    <script>
      let email = 'private@gmail.com';
      let pw = 'private';

      firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pw)
        .then((ac) => {
          console.log('It worked.');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error.toString());
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Test
  </body>
</html>
```

Just an update to say I've followed the instructions on both of these pages, made sure I have all the pre-requisites, etc.  I feel like there's some underlying assumption that is made but not communicated:

https://medium.com/@ThatJenPerson/whos-there-implementing-identity-platform-for-web-c210c6839d3b

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/google

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bug in GCP/Identity Platform.

If you start in Identity Platform, it will generate an API key for you.  If you look at the Firebase console, the API Key will match there.  ...but it won't work (for anything it seems).

If you then create an app (seemingly any app) it will regenerate the **project** API Key (which doesn't seem right).  You don't need any of the App configuration information - just the `apiKey` and `authDomain` are required from the project, but now the API key (at the project level, not the App level) is regenerated (and GCP Identity Platform will now reflect this new key), and that newly generated API Key will work correctly.

The app can just be an HTML file sitting on your local computer and it will still work - but only if you set up SOME app in Firebase (even though you never use it for anything).

Answer (score 0):

It seems problematic that both the `projectId` and `appId` are missing from the config. In my multiple Firebase authentication implementations, I always include those.

Inside your `Firebase Project Settings`, scroll down and copy the entire config just to be certain:

https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/<YOUR_PROJECT_NAME_HERE>/settings/general

**EDIT (MORE INFO)

After visiting `https://console.firebase.google.com` and selecting your project, click the little `gear icon` in the top left > `Project Settings` > (scroll all the way down to the code sample they give you)

You would see something like this:

[image]

In this screenshot (purposely cut-off) you'll see:

const firebaseCon....

That's the entire config you need to be using - I've setup dozens of Firebase Firestore projects with all services and I don't leave out the `projectId` and `appId` ever.

Another thing to make sure of is that your `Firebase Authentication` has `Email / Password` enabled. Go to `Build > Authentication > Sign-in method`. Then make sure you've added and enabled `Email/Password` option.

[image]

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "scroll down and copy the entire config".  There is a "Your Project" section with config information, but I don't have to scroll down to it, and it isn't a code snippet so I'm not sure how to integrate the information there into my sample.

Comment: ...also, neither the official Google documentation or the Google Cloud Tech video (or associated medium article) include anything other than apiKey and authDomain.

Comment: Go here: 
https://console.firebase.google.com

Click your project box.
Click the gear icon > Projects Settings > then scroll all the way down.

You should see "Your apps" and if you registered and setup your app, you should see an entire config with more properties than just 2 that you provide in your example.

Another thing to look at is on the left-hand side:

Build > Authentication > Sign-in Method.

Make sure that Email/Password is enabled!

Comment: It isn't a pure firebase app but none of the documents I've linked to indicate this is a pre-requisite.  Nothing you mention is in any of the 'getting started' documents from Google, and the Google Cloud Tech accompanying article even lists pre-requisites explicitly and doesn't indicate you have to set up an app in Firebase.  All it says is that a project will be automatically created when Identity Platform is enabled in GCP.  
I mean - it may very well be that what you are suggesting works but it seems like Google intends for this to be usable elsewhere.

Comment: ...so, as I didn't just come out and say it - there's no code sample there for me to copy because I don't have a Firebase App, but given that is never referenced anywhere in Identity Platform documentation, it seems like it shouldn't be a requirement.

Comment: I figured it out.  See my answer below.  Its just a bug in the console (as far as I can tell), the code I've posted above works as is.

Comment: Ah, okay good to know. I haven't used Identity Platform directly in the way you are using - I should try that because things are different there. The main thing is you got it to work! :) Upvoted, very interesting!

Comment: Thanks for helping - I may never have gone there and created an app to check it out without this guidance.